# Remove annoying calculate button from Magento 2 Bundle Page layout

Tags: magento2, javascript, bundled-product

I have set up a bundle product and its working but can I disable the javascript that forces me to click on calculate every time I use it?

I want it to open in "calculate mode". I dont know what Im doing wrong. is it bundle.js or slide.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually it's found in Magento Bundle summary.phtml

```
/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/summary.phtml
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    ".product-add-form": {
        "slide": {
            "slideSpeed": 1500,
            "slideSelector": "#bundle-slide",
            "slideBackSelector": ".action.customization.back",
            "bundleProductSelector": "#bundleProduct",
            "bundleOptionsContainer": ".product-add-form"
            <?php if ($block->isStartCustomization()): ?>
            ,"autostart": true
            <?php endif;?>
        }
    }
}
```

and you need to override it and remove the if condition in

```
Vendor/Theme/Magento_Bundle/templates/catalog/product/view/summary.phtml
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".product-add-form": {
            "slide": {
                "slideSpeed": 1500,
                "slideSelector": "#bundle-slide",
                "slideBackSelector": ".action.customization.back",
                "bundleProductSelector": "#bundleProduct",
                "bundleOptionsContainer": ".product-add-form"
                ,"autostart": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try it now! Be right BACK :-)

Comment: Its strange. It loads only the attributes, not the main bundle container.. Any ideas?

Comment: Its working! Now I just need to figure out howto make it disappear for good!