# Magento2 How to remove bundle product options slide

Tags: magento2

Magento2 How to remove bundle product options slide totally. I need the options to be displayed normally when page loads not in a slide effect.

Please someone can guide me on this?

I tried this but didn't work as I need

[Remove annoying calculate button from Magento 2 Bundle Page layout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260262/remove-annoying-calculate-button-from-magento-2-bundle-page-layout)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a solution for this either. Any lucky ?